# How can I display a Google map for city?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to display a Google map when a user searches for a city and presses the search button, but I do not understand how to do it properly. Here is my code done so far.  I don't get how to take user input and check that city is in the array.  If it is in the array then it should display it on the Google map.  For example, if the user types the city name Houston, USA then it should display on the Google map after checking whether the city name is in our database.

Script:

```
function searchResult(cityname) { 
    var namesOfCity = ["houston,boston,newyork,florida"];

    //check the user input 

    //if match display it on google map    
}

function initialize() 
{
        if(GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
            map.setUIToDefault();
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">


 <input type="text" id="cityname" value="" name=""/>
  <input id="search" type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchResult('cityname')" />
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 450px; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: **Just an FYI:**  Google Maps is now using API version 3 which no longer requires the inline JavaScript `onload` and `onunload` within the `body` tag, among other huge improvements.   See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but you are not initialising your array correctly.

You are also not storing the correct coordinates for each city in your array.

Instead, try using a custom object to store the names of allowed cities and their coordinates (latitude and longitude) and looking at that to determine what to display:

```
function searchResult(cityname) { 
    var cities = {
        houston: { 
           lat: /* ... */,
           long: /* ... */
        },
        boston: { 
           lat: /* ... */,
           long: /* ... */
        },
        'new york': { // note the quotes due to a space in the name
           lat: /* ... */,
           long: /* ... */
        },
        florida: { 
           lat: /* ... */,
           long: /* ... */
        }
    };

    //check the user input 
    var textfield = document.getElementById(cityname);

    if (textfield) {
        // look up the lowercase version of the value typed in
        var coords = cities[textfield.value.toLowerCase()];
        //if match display it on google map   
        if (coords) {
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(coords.lat, coords.long), 13); // you could also make the zoom level a property of each city, which would allow you to customise that per city
            map.setUIToDefault();
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: how to find out latitude and longtitude ?

Comment: Look it up in Google Maps or Google Earth for each city, to determine the best possible center point and zoom level to use. This would give you the most dependable and reliable results.

Comment: but how to get automatically ??

Comment: You could get it automatically using the geocoding API as Jasper mentioned, but you may find getting the zoom level right tricky to ensure that you show a complete view of the city in the map area. That's why I am thinking you might be better off working out the optimum zoom level first manually, and just using that.

Answer (score 2):

Your array needs more quotes to make each index a string of it's own:

```
//instead of using the inline click handler, this will bind a click event handler to your search button
$('#search').bind('click', searchResults);

//this is the click event handler for the search button
function searchResult(event) {

    //stop the default behavior of the button
    event.preventDefault();

    //cache whitelist of cities and the city that the user typed into the input
    var namesOfCity   = ["houston", "boston", "newyork", "florida"],
        inputValue    = $('#cityname').val().toLowerCase(),//notice the input has been made lower-case to attempt to match it to an index in the namesOfCity array
        inputAccepted = false;

    //iterate through the array of accepted city names
    for (var i = 0, len = namesOfCity.length; i < len; i++) {

        //check if the current index is equal to user's input
        if (inputValue == namesOfCity[i]) {

            //if the current index is equal to the user's input then set a flag to show that fact and stop the loop from iterating any further
            inputAccepted = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    //if match display it on google map
    if (inputAccepted === true) {
        //update the map here
    }   
}
```

You can use Google's Geocoding service to turn a city name into longitude/latitude coordinates: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/ (I'll let you experiment with those instructions)

Comment: iam nt getting how to get could u please give a example